# Covariance of Brownian bridge increments

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, covariance

$\text{I need to prove the following:}\\$
$$\text{Cov}[\left(W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)\right),\left(W(t_{j+1})-W(t_j)\right)|Z]=    
\begin{cases}
\left(t_{i+1}-t_i\right)-\frac{\displaystyle\left(t_{i+1}-t_i\right)^2}{\displaystyle T} &\text{if  } i=j\\
-\frac{\displaystyle\left(t_{i+1}-t_i\right)\left(t_{j+1}-t_j\right)}{\displaystyle T} &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
$$ where $ W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion and $Z=\frac{W_T}{\sqrt{T}}$ is an $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable standard Gaussian random variable.
My guess is that this could be done using some results for the Brownian bridge.
Also, I was searching for the answer to this question on this website and there are some hints you can find, but somehow I cannot come to the endpoint.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\widetilde{W}(t)=W(t)-\frac{t}TW(T)$, since $\{\widetilde{W}(t),\,0\le t\le T\}$ is a gaussian process and uncorrelated with $Z=\frac{W(T)}{\sqrt{T}}$, therefore $\{\widetilde{W}(t),\,0\le t\le T\}$ is independent with $Z$ too and 
\begin{gather} \mathsf{E}[\widetilde{W}(t)|Z]=0,\quad \mathsf{E}[\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i)|Z]\stackrel{\text{def}}=\mathsf{E}[\widetilde{W}(t_{i+1})-\widetilde{W}(t_i)|Z]=0, \quad \mathsf{E}[\Delta W(t_i)|Z]=\frac{\Delta t_i}{\sqrt{T}}Z.\\
\mathsf{E}[\widetilde{W}(s)\widetilde{W}(t)]=\mathsf{E}[W(s)W(t)]-\frac{st}{T^2}\mathsf{E}[W^2(T)]=s\wedge t-\frac{st}T.\\
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{cov}[\Delta W(t_i),\Delta W(t_j)|Z]
&=\mathsf{cov}[\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i),\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_j)|Z]
=\mathsf{E}[\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i)\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_j)]\\
&=\begin{cases}
\Delta t_i-\dfrac{(\Delta t_i)^2}{T}, & i=j,\\
-\dfrac{\Delta t_i\Delta t_j}{T}, &i\ne j.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

Some complements of above expressions: **1**. Since $\mathsf{E}[W(T)]=0$ and 
$$\mathsf{E}[\widetilde{W}(t)]=\mathsf{E}\Bigl[W(t)-\frac{t}TW(T)\Bigl]=\mathsf{E}[W(t)]-\frac{t}T\mathsf{E}[W(T)]=0,$$ then
$$\mathsf{cov}[\widetilde{W}(t),Z]=\mathsf{E}[\widetilde{W}(t)Z]-\mathsf{E}[\widetilde{W}(t)]\mathsf{E}{Z}=\mathsf{E}[W(t)Z]-\frac{t}{\sqrt{T}}\mathsf{E}[Z^2]
=\frac{t}{\sqrt{T}}-\frac{t}{\sqrt{T}}=0.$$
Therefore, $\{\widetilde{W}(t),0\le t\le T\}$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated. Meanwhile, $\{\widetilde{W}(t),0\le t\le T,Z=\frac{W(T)}{\sqrt{T}}\}$ is Gaussian, So
$\{\widetilde{W}(t),0\le t\le T\}$ and $Z$ are independent too.

**4**. Since $\Delta W(t_i)-\mathsf{E}(\Delta W(t_i)|Z)=\Delta W(t_i)-\frac{\Delta t_i}{\sqrt{T}}Z=\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i)$, therefore
\begin{align} \mathsf{cov}[\Delta W(t_i),\Delta W(t_j)|Z] &=\mathsf{E}[(\Delta W(t_i)-\mathsf{E}(\Delta W(t_i)|Z))(\Delta W(t_j)-\mathsf{E}(\Delta W(t_j)|Z))|Z]\\
&=\mathsf{E}\Bigl[\Bigl(\Delta W(t_i)-\frac{\Delta t_i}{\sqrt{T}}Z\Bigr)\Bigl(\Delta W(t_j)-\frac{\Delta t_j}{\sqrt{T}}Z\Bigr)\Bigr] \\ &=\mathsf{E}[\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i)\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_j)|Z]=\mathsf{E}[\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i)\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_j)].
\end{align}
Similarly, since $\mathsf{E}[\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i)|Z]=0$ and
$$ \mathsf{cov}[\Delta\widetilde W(t_i),\Delta\widetilde W(t_j)|Z]=\mathsf{E}[\Delta\widetilde W(t_i) \Delta\widetilde W(t_j)|Z]=\mathsf{E}[\Delta\widetilde W(t_i) \Delta\widetilde W(t_j)].
$$
**5**. For $i<j$ (i.e. $i+1\le j$),
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[&\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_i)\Delta\widetilde{W}(t_j)]
=\mathsf{E}[(\widetilde{W}(t_{i+1})-\widetilde{W}(t_i))(\widetilde{W}(t_{j+1})-\widetilde{W}(t_j)]\\
&=(t_{i+1}\wedge t_{j+1}-t_i\wedge t_{j+1})-\frac{(t_{i+1}-t_i)t_{j+1}}{T}
 -(t_{i+1}\wedge t_j -t_i\wedge t_j)-\frac{(t_{i+1}-t_i)t_{j}}{T}\\
&=(t_{i+1}-t_i)-(t_{i+1}-t_i)-\frac{(t_{i+1}-t_i)(t_{j+1}-t_j)}{T}\\
&=-\frac{\Delta t_i\Delta t_j}T.
\end{align}

Comment: Dear @JGWang, first of all thank you for your reply. However, there are some spots in the proof that i don't understand. 1) Why do you claim that $\widetilde{W(t)}$ is uncorrelated and independent of $Z$? 2) How did you compute $E[\Delta W(t_i) \vert Z]$ 3) Why do two middle terms of the product in $E[\widetilde{W(s)}\widetilde{W(t)}]$ vanish? 4) Why do the covariances for $W(t_i)$ and for $\widetilde{W(t_i)}$ are equal? 5) How do you get the result for $i \neq j$ ?

Comment: @Tata, Since all answers of your questions could got from direct calculations, I just write down the first and last one in above answer. If you still have some difficult, please let me know, I like do my best to help you.

Comment: Dear @JGWang, thank you very much. I am probably missing some important concept, so that I cannot understand some things coming out of the direct calculations. 1) when I calculate $E[\Delta W(t_i) \vert Z]$ I get $\frac{\Delta t_i}{T}E[W(T) \vert Z]$ where you get just $Z$ instead of the last expectation. Why it is like that? 2) While calculating $E[W(T)Z]$ you "say" that it is equal to $E[W(T)^2]$ but not $E[\frac{W(T)^2}{\sqrt T}]$. Hence I don't understand why we simply neglect $\sqrt T$ there? And also why both covariances are equal? I would appreciate if you provide some explanation here.

Comment: @Tata，Thank you to point out my mistakes, I had confused the $Z$ and $W(T)$ in several expressions. Now I correct it. If there any other errors, please tell me, I will correct it. Thank you again.

Comment: Dear @JGWang, thank you for your help. However I still do not understand why both covariances are equal.

Comment: @Tata, Thank you for your replications. I add a 'complement 4' to interpret 'both covariances are equal'.

Comment: Dear @JGWang, now all steps of your proof are clear to me so far. Thank you very much! You have helped me out a lot!

Comment: @Tata， You are welcome.